# With Citrix ICO how can I identify which wfica32 process is started by current program?

Tags: citrix

Now we are using Citrix XenApp5.0 to publish application and using ICA Client Object (ICO) to access it from client, to implement some features we need to know the exact process id (or window handle) of wfica.exe which is started by current program (Since there may have multiple same programs running, we can't identify them with app name, windows title, etc.). In all of interfaces provided by ICA Client Object I can't find something useful. Can anybody give me some clue? Thanks!

Comment: Are you still interested by an answer to that old question?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the process to be a child process of your process. You can verify that using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: We can't use this way since one process (wfcrun32.exe) spawn multiple sub processes (wfica32.exe). When we try to start a new ICA session, the ICA object will notify the existing wfcrun32.exe to start a new wfica32.exe and then use wfca32.exe to create new ICA session, so we don't know which wfica32.exe process is the new created